# Linux and apache tika issue

Tags: linux, apache-tika

Im using tika-app.jar with the version 1.12,to try to find the list of corrupted files that can't be opened in a specified folder.
the problem is when i tested inside windows it gives me in the log folder some exception that allow me to know what files that can't be opened like this :

```
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'folder\mi-am-CV.docx'
```

but the problem in linux is only i get a broad error in the log folder like this:

```
WARN  org.apache.tika.batch.FileResourceConsumer  - <parse_ex resourceId="test-corrupted-2.doc">org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@f6e9bd4
```

so i can't know specificaly what files that are really corrupted and can't be opened.
here's the shell command that i use for that in linux :

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j_driver.xml -cp "bin/*" org.apache.tika.cli.TikaCLI -JXX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -JXmx5g -JDlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -bc tika-batch-config-basic-test.xml -i /folder -o outxml -numConsumers 10
```

thanks.

Comment: You can `grep` the result and look for `WARN` messages...

Comment: the problem is not in grep, the problem is i don't get this information " Can't open the specified file:" to grep on it.

Comment: Isn't the resourceId the name of the file with the problem?

Comment: yeah, but in linux can't get the flag Can't open the specified file to grep on it because the folders contains many files raising false alarm when using tika-app.jar